List comprehension only outputs 1 line instead of multiple lines in sequence of triangular numbers
    tri_num = []
    for i in range(1, 10):
        tri_num.append(i*(i+1)//2) 
        print(tri_num)

Hi, I'm taking a course in Python and we've been asked to write a list comprehension that creates exactly the same list below, produced by the above code.  The output for this is below:
    [1]
    [1, 3]
    [1, 3, 6]
    [1, 3, 6, 10]
    [1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
    [1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21]
    [1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28]
    [1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36]
    [1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45]


I have written the following code for the list comprehension and come up with the following:
    tri_num = [(i*(i+1)//2)for i in range (1, 10)]
    print(tri_num)


output:

    [1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45]

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!!!
Thank you!
I have tried multiple variations of this list comprehension, without success.

In your first example, there's a print statement in the loop, so you print each partial result, but why don't you check the final list to see how it looks like? In the second case, you print after the list has been built.

I'm not sure I understand your question: It appears that both the for loop and the list comprehension are producing the same result.

BTW If you have been tasked with creating the same list, you have already succeeded. Maybe the print in the first example was supposed to be indented outside the loop?

Are you supposed to create the final list only, as you have, or the list of lists, printing each one out successively?

Apologies if I wasn't clear in what I was asking.  Basically I need to produce a list identical to the list that was printed out by the given code.  The list comprehension should print out the list in successive numbers as it did for the initial code given, not just the final line of output i.e.-  [1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45]    I greatly appreciate the input and help!!

Related to Printing using list comprehension

I will say that of course you should do what the assignment asks, but it’s a bad assignment b/c printing from a list comprehension is an abuse of list comprehensions.

Actually I’d argue the above is a reasonable reason to close this question: outside of an artificial homework assignment, answers aren't likely to be relevant in real life. And SO isn’t a homework answering site.

Bob - understood.  Just thought I'd ask for some help after wracking my brain in trying to come up with a solution.

I think some commenters above misunderstood the question. It makes sense.

tri_num = []
[tri_num.append(i*(i+1)//2) or print(tri_num) for i in range(1, 10)]


Although a list comprehension should never be used this way, This is abusing a comprehension to run side effects.

Agreed. This is an odd situation in which the question is asking for bad code b/c the assignment asks for one to abuse Python.

The solution is simple, and the question is pretty legible. Nested list comprehensions come to rescue:
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> x = [[(j*(j+1)//2) for j in range(1, i + 2)] for i in range(9)]
>>> pprint(x)
[[1],
 [1, 3],
 [1, 3, 6],
 [1, 3, 6, 10],
 [1, 3, 6, 10, 15],
 [1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21],
 [1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28],
 [1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36],
 [1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45]]


The OP seems to be expecting the same list as the one they created in the first snippet (x[-1] in your example), not a nested list. Also, as they pointed in their comments The list comprehension should print out the list in successive numbers as it did for the initial code given, which means IIUC that they expect printing as a side effect of the comprehension.
